# Blacklisting words that can be entered into a MySQL database via a php form using regex

Tags: php, mysql, regex, blacklist

Okay, at the moment on my site I have a feature that blacklists words, and if it detects them when the form is submitted, the post is not submitted, here it is:

```
$disallowedWords = array(
'list','of','bad','words'
);

foreach ($disallowedWords as $word) {
  if (preg_match("/\s+$word\s+/i", $entry)) {
    die('The word or phrase ' . $word . ' is not allowed...');
  }
}

$urlRegex = '(http|https|ftp)\://([a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+(\:[a-zA-Z0-9\.&amp;%\$\-]+)*@)*((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]{1}[0-9]{2}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}|[1-9])\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]{1}[0-9]{2}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}|[1-9]|0)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]{1}[0-9]{2}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}|[1-9]|0)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]{1}[0-9]{2}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}|[0-9])|localhost|([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)*[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.(com|edu|gov|int|mil|net|org|biz|arpa|info|name|pro|aero|coop|museum|[a-zA-Z]{2}))(\:[0-9]+)*(/($|[a-zA-Z0-9\.\,\?\'\\\+&amp;%\$#\=~_\-]+))*';
if (preg_match($urlRegex, $entry)) {
  die('The word or phrase ' . $word . ' is not allowed...');

}
```

This works for sentences like this:

> Here is a list

It would stop the post and say the word list wasn't allowed, however if I put:

> here is a listt

or

> here is alist

It doesn't work, so, how (if it's even possible) could I make it censor that exact letter combination? Or whatever would work to the effect that I couldn't enter 'listt' or 'alist' etc.

Comment: Good lucK: http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/The-Clbuttic-Mistake-.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the two instances of '\s+' from your Regex will do what you're asking, but it will also blacklist any (potentially valid) word that contains a 'bad word'

Comment: Works great, I see you point, which is why only very specific words will be on the blacklist without the \s+ and other less offensive words will be on the original.

Comment: I hope no one starts a thread on your site about Shittake mushrooms.

Answer (score 1):

Using `\b$word\b` instead of `\s$word\s` will also match words surrounded by punctuation or the beginning/end of the string.  (Technically, `\b` is a [zero-width assertion](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Assertions) that matches the boundary between word and non-word characters.)

Of course, this still won't solve the [Scunthorpe problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem).

Answer (score 0):

you would want to take `\s+` off each side of your regex query.

on a side note, why not use strpos() instead?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

or better yet, instead of stopping them if a blacklisted word is found, just replace each blacklisted word with `****` or something.

Comment: I tried strpos() - It was to specific (see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7780631/detecting-specific-words-in-a-textarea-submission/7780702#7780702 ) Even if I had written the code right, it wouldn't have worked

Comment: @Aviate, I have no idea what you are talking about. strpos() works great for exactly what you are trying to do. `if (strpos($entry, $word) !== false) echo 'You cannot use the word' . $word;`