# detecting and allowing only specific words in a textarea

Tags: html, forms, textarea

how can i detect and allow only some specific words in my text area? I found this
[Detecting specific words in a textarea submission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7780631/detecting-specific-words-in-a-textarea-submission) but the answer provided is to detect and not allow the words specified, but what i need is my text area to detect and only allow specific words,

sample, text area would only accept `green` and `blue` word and would not accept any other color word, hence, a pop up would show advising that its only accepting `green` or `blue`

Comment: html select option group, radio button or checkbox?...I think

Comment: 1. get the textarea's contents 2.

Comment: How sure are you not to need a Drop-Down Box for selection? :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$subject = "I have a green car"; // here you can use `$_POST['txt_area_name']` to get the textarea value
$pattern = '/green/';
$matched = preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
if($matched == 1){
//do stuff here
}else {
//do stuff here
}
?>
```

Here `1` means `Match found` and viseversa.