# MongoDB $in Operator Limit when using Array from sed command

Tags: arrays, bash, mongodb, sed

I am trying to run through huge amount of data. The problem is when I pass 100 objects in array it works perfectly fine but moment I keep 150 or more it starts failing .

Example :--

```
DBQuery.shellBatchSize = 100000 ; 
permissibleCars = [  "C:1456797:665","C:146:5722","C:145:57805","C:146:6070","C:14:60908"]
db.getCollection('contracts').aggregate([
{$match:
  {         "methods.name": "image",
            "methods.status": "ACTIVE",   
            container: {"$in": permissibleCars},
            Class : "Download"

} },            
 {"$group" : {_id:"$container", count:{$sum:1}}}],
 { allowDiskUse: true}
);
```

This will work perfectly fine till the limit in permissibleCars  is low say 100 but the moment it crosses 150 or so it starts failing randomly with below error.

```
2017-08-16T21:30:35.101+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] SyntaxError: unterminated string literal @(shell):1:4091
2017-08-16T21:30:35.132+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] SyntaxError: missing ; before statement @(shell):1:6
2017-08-16T21:30:35.162+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] SyntaxError: missing ; before statement @(shell):1:2
2017-08-16T21:30:35.193+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] ReferenceError: permissibleCars is not defined :
```

Now since it runs fine it cannot be syntax issue .

Anyway to get this fixed so that I can pass larger number of variables. I am running this through shell .

```
 for((i=0; i < ${#arr[@]}; i+=batchsize))
   do
    set display=lastline
    IFS=,
    part=( "${arr[@]:i:batchsize}" )
    { echo "DBQuery.shellBatchSize = $contracts_count ; "; cat query/container_count_tmp.js; } > query/container_count.js
    sed -i  "2i permissibleCars = [  ${part[*]} ]"  query/container_count.js
    mongo mngdb-test-02:27068/test_db -u test_user -p test123 < query/container_count.js >> output/container_count.txt
 done
```

Array Declation :--

```
distinct_array=`sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g' output/userdistinct.txt`
declare -a arr=($distinct_array)
echo " Total Number of Distinct Ids Stored in Array ${#arr[@]}"
batchsize=150
```

Any help will be highly appreciated. 
Note :-- I checked the page [mongodb $in limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11305249/mongodb-in-limit) not much of information .

Have uploaded the sample data at for testing and to replicate the issue . https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByHEfbo541jIYlJhSGJIdElCODQ/view?usp=sharing

Regards,

Comment: This is **not** a MongoDB problem. The problem is that your own batch file construction is incorrect. You are actually being told that the error is an "unterminated string literal", which is a "syntax" error and nothing to do with the number of arguments given to `$in`.

Comment: Hi. In that case it should even fail for 100 . But it is filing only if number is going high

Answer (score 0):

This is not a MongoDB limitation, but if you are using POSIX standard sed implementation, the byte length limit is 8192 bytes. That would explains why you have a syntax error due to the array string has been truncated.

https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Limitations.html

For a workaround, use perl instead of sed:

perl -ni -e "print; print 'permissibleCars = [  ${part[*]} ]' if $. == 2" query/container_count.js

Comment: Use perl:
perl -ni -e "print; print \"permissibleCars = [  ${part[*]} ]\n\" if $. == 2" query/container_count.js

Comment: This keeps failing with error :--root@vm-test-001:~/mongosearch# perl -ni -e "print; print \"permissibleCars = [ ${part[*]} ]\n\" if $. == 2" query/container_count.js
Bareword found where operator expected at -e line 1, near ""permissibleCars = [ "C"
        (Missing operator before C?)

Comment: Should escape " with \"

Comment: yes .. echo $part "C:00000092666270:53882159774" ..tried using this comnand also ..perl -ni -e 'print; print "permissibleCars = [ \${part[*]} ]\n" if $. == 2' query/container_count.js but it keeps inserting it as text rather than variable

Comment: perl -ni -e "print; print 'permissibleCars = [  ${part[*]} ]' if $. == 2" query/container_count.js

Comment: I think the issue is with Mongo itself as I tried every possible trick using perl , sed , awk  , print but it doesnt take after a limit.

Comment: It works perfectly fine on Mongo UI like robomongo but if the connection is called form unix box it doesnt work beyond a limit.

Comment: Ok, so the issue is at POSIX length limit for command line arguments. Can you tell me which Unix/linux distro are you using

Comment: root@vm-test-001:~#  xargs --show-limits
Your environment variables take up 1898 bytes
POSIX upper limit on argument length (this system): 2093206
POSIX smallest allowable upper limit on argument length (all systems): 4096
Maximum length of command we could actually use: 2091308
Size of command buffer we are actually using: 131072
Maximum parallelism (--max-procs must be no greater): 2147483647

Comment: I think it is POSIX smallest allowable upper limit on argument length (all systems): which is causing it.

Comment: Linux version 4.4.0-21-generic (buildd@lgw01-21) (gcc version 5.3.1 20160413 (Ubuntu 5.3.1-14ubuntu2)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152213/discussion-between-user2854333-and-anhlc).